# Parameterized functors

Tags: ocaml, functor

Suppose I have these signatures :

```
module type CharS = sig
type c
  type t = BoW | C of c | EoW

  val compare : t -> t -> int

  val print : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
end

module type GraphemS = sig

  type c
  type t

  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val print : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
end
```

And these two functors :

```
module MakeDiGraphem (C : CharS) : GraphemS with type c = C.t = struct

  type c = C.t
  type t = c * c

  let compare (cb1, ce1) (cb2, ce2) =
    let r1 = C.compare cb1 cb2 in
    if r1 = 0 then
      C.compare ce1 ce2
    else r1

  let print fmt (cb, ce) =
    Format.fprintf fmt "@[%a%a@]@," C.print cb C.print ce

end

module MakeMonoGraphem (C : CharS) : GraphemS with type c = C.t = struct

  type c = C.t
  type t = c

  let compare c1 c2 = C.compare c1 c2

  let print fmt c =
    Format.fprintf fmt "@[%a@]@," C.print c

end
```

Now, I'd like to have a functor which would allow me to create a module of type GraphemS with either the first functor or the second one. What I did is this :

```
module type SizeS = sig
  type t = int

  val param : int
end

module MakeGraphem (C : CharS) (I : SizeS) : GraphemS with type c = C.t = struct
  module MonoGraphem = MakeMonoGraphem(C)
  module DiGraphem = MakeDiGraphem(C)

  let select_graphem =
    if I.param = 1 then
      (module MonoGraphem : GraphemS)
    else
      (module DiGraphem : GraphemS)

  include (val select_graphem)

end
```

But sadly I got :

> Error: This expression creates fresh types.
>
> It is not allowed inside applicative functors.

My question is, then, is it possible to do what I want to do and what does this error means ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you are not allowed to do first-class calculations in an applicative functor application include. Basically, the typing system has no guarantee that `I.param` is a constant so it can't ensure that the functor will always return the same type. An applicative functor (the default in OCaml) has to always return the same type for the same expression (in a sense, it's pure).

If you are on OCaml 4.02 or more, you can declare your functor as generative through a [unit argument](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec252):

```
module MakeGraphem (C : CharS) (I : SizeS) () :
           GraphemS with type c = C.t = struct
```

My favorite way of doing the trick would be to get the functor to apply as an argument instead of `I`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was trying to make it work because I had a lot of signature problem. I used the functor as an argument (I wanted to do that but I didn't think it was possible, hence my cheat with this "parameter").

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't understand the generative functors feature (direct link: https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/generativefunctors.html)

Comment: And what do you mean when you say, "My favorite way of doing the trick would be to get the functor to apply as an argument instead of I"?